# Using amsmath and mathabx messes up stacking a widehat on a vec

Tags: amsmath, mathabx

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[\widehat{\vec{v}_{i-1}}\]

\end{document}
```

What I expect this to generate is a widehat over the entire `\vec{v}_{i-1}`, but instead the various components are randomly spaced and overlapping.  If I remove either `amsmath` or `mathabx`, the problem goes away.  How should I fix this?  I need to typeset this in a paper that makes essential use of both `amsmath` and `mathabx`.

Comment: Interesting... A temporary solution is to reset the definition `\def\widehat{\mathaccent "0362}` _after_ `\usepackage{mathabx}`.   Or you can use `\let\OldWidehat\widehat`
`\usepackage{mathabx}`
`\let\widehat\OldWidehat`
`.  Not sure if this will break other things though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `amsmath` uses a quite complicated way of dealing with math accents, in order to be able to stack two of them correctly, it doesn't modify the definition of `\widehat` (and `\widetilde`). However, it does redefine the workings of `\DeclareMathAccent`, so that accents declared after loading it use the code for stacking accents.

On the other hand, `mathabx` isn't really compatible with `amsmath`, as it does redefinitions that obliterate several `amsmath` features.

The solution for the specific problem is to reinstate working definitions for `\widehat` and `\widetilde`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\renewcommand{\widehat}{\mathaccent "0670\relax}
\renewcommand{\widetilde}{\mathaccent "0672\relax}

\begin{document}

\[\widehat{\vec{v}_{i-1}}\qquad \widetilde{\vec{v}_{i-1}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should probably import the symbols you need, rather than loading the whole `mathabx`, see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need `mathx` family, using only `\usepackage[matha,mathb]{mathabx}` it works.

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[matha,mathb]{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[\widehat{\vec{v}_{i-1}}\]

\end{document}
```

Otherwise, here is a dirty workaround:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\[
\stackinset{c}{}{t}{-3pt}{$\widehat{\phantom{{v}_{i-1}}}$}{$\vec{v}_{i-1}$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]