# Widecheck with hat does not work

Tags: accents

I defined new `check` from the internet, and re defined `hat` with `widehat` using `amsmath`. But this compiles somewhat strange. My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\hat}{\widehat}
%%widecheck
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<-> mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}
\renewcommand{\check}{\widecheck}

\begin{document}

$\check{\hat{f}(-\xi)}(-x)$

\end{document}
```

And this compiles like:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it's caused by the same bug as  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/250119 ■ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392968/250119 . Commenting out `amsmath` works, for one. (or putting the lines before \usepackage{amsmath}